# Accelerated Database Recovery - Should I turn it on for system databases

Tags: sql-server

I've just upgraded to SQL Server 2019 and I'm turning on ADR for all the user databases, but my question is, should I also be doing the system databases?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. Tried it on the model database and got this answer:

Msg 12122, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
Accelerated Database Recovery cannot be enabled/disabled on system databases.